# Does infura support rinkeby event listening

Tags: web3js, events, infura, rinkeby

Hi I ran a simple voting example connecting to https://rinkeby.infura.io/ since I do not run local Eth node. Everything works fine except event watching.

var event2 = contractInstance.EventTester();
event2.watch(function(error, result){
 if (!error){
 console.log(result);
 }else {console.log(‘ERROR’)}
});

When I submit a transaction I do not see that the event was fired (it is called in the contract function). Am I missing anything ?

Comment: you're doing something wrong because these work

Answer (score 2):

I have been having horrible problems catching events in Rinkeby test net using Metamask. I know things work because I can use Metamask though localhost (testrpc) and it works fine, but it is extremely intermittent with Metamask.

This seems to be a really common issue. I have solved it by instead logging the tx hash that is returned when you make a tx, and then calling web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash) until it returns not null, and parsing the events from there.

Hopefully this helps. Of course this isn’t viable in all situations.

Comment: This has been giving me a head ache! Glad to see it is a common problem